# How does the front-end code execute the back-end code in Web apps?

Tags: javascript, web

I understand that yes there is a front-end and a back-end. But how do those two communicate?

So for example,

1. I go to https://www.google.com/
2. Google server responds to me with some minified resources consisting of HTML, CSS, and some JS.
3. I type "How does the front-end talk to the back-end?" into Google
4. I click "Google Search" or press return
5. ???

My lack of understanding comes from the fact that I haven't ever shipped anything to production in terms of web apps I think. I've always just developed locally and so I'd say something like `href=/...` and it would just be some directory that I have locally. Or maybe I'd call some JS function that is bundled up in the same app.

So at step number 5 is there some JS that already is living in my web browser that is executing an HTTP call using something like `XMLHttpRequest` which hits Google servers and gets directed towards some service in their backend? Is there a way I can see that in the developer console?

Concrete examples appreciated.

Comment: Go to the Network tab of the console.

Comment: Doing a Google search doesn't require XMLHttpRequest. It simply submits the form to the server, the server runs a program that finds the matches, and it returns a new web page with all the links.

Comment: The basic method to talk to a server is to use a <form>; it has an `action` attribute which is the new URL that gets loaded. The basic mechanism is a [GET or POST request](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol#Request_message), depending on which kind of data you're sending along. This is done by the browser when you click a link or send a form, and the server will answer that request with a new HMTL document usually.

Comment: Adding to what others have said, if you open the browser's dev tools and select the "network" tab you can see all the network requests and responses for the current page. The list clears out when you navigate to a new page unless you check the "Preserve log" box. Selecting a request in the list reveals lots of details about what was sent to the server, how it was sent, and what the server's response was. Check out [this guide](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network) to get started with it.

Comment: Thanks y'all, and thanks @rayhatfield for the resource. I'll take a look